# Tem como diminuir este script sem perder a funcionalidade?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-hover, addclass

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("div#contenthead div.left span").hover(function() {
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu").addClass("displayblock");});

    $("div#contenthead div.left span.cursos").hover(function() {
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.cursos").addClass("displayblock");
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.atendimento").removeClass("displayblock");
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.acaosocial").removeClass("displayblock");
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.calendario").removeClass("displayblock");});

    $("div#contenthead div.left span.atendimento").hover(function() {
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.cursos").removeClass("displayblock");
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.atendimento").addClass("displayblock");
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.acaosocial").removeClass("displayblock");
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.calendario").removeClass("displayblock");});

    $("div#contenthead div.left span.acaosocial").hover(function() {
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.cursos").removeClass("displayblock");
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.atendimento").removeClass("displayblock");
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.acaosocial").addClass("displayblock");
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.calendario").removeClass("displayblock");});

    $("div#contenthead div.left span.calendario").hover(function() {
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.cursos").removeClass("displayblock");
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.atendimento").removeClass("displayblock");
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.acaosocial").removeClass("displayblock");
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.calendario").addClass("displayblock");});

    $("div#contenthead div.right span.login").hover(function() {
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.cursos").removeClass("displayblock");
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.atendimento").removeClass("displayblock");
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.acaosocial").removeClass("displayblock");
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.calendario").removeClass("displayblock");});

    $("div#contenthead div.left span.cursos").hover(function() {
        $("div#contenthead div.left span.cursos").addClass("colorblue");
        $("div#contenthead div.left span.atendimento").removeClass("colorblue");
        $("div#contenthead div.left span.acaosocial").removeClass("colorblue");
        $("div#contenthead div.left span.calendario").removeClass("colorblue");});

    $("div#contenthead div.left span.atendimento").hover(function() {
        $("div#contenthead div.left span.cursos").removeClass("colorblue");
        $("div#contenthead div.left span.atendimento").addClass("colorblue");
        $("div#contenthead div.left span.acaosocial").removeClass("colorblue");
        $("div#contenthead div.left span.calendario").removeClass("colorblue");});

    $("div#contenthead div.left span.acaosocial").hover(function() {
        $("div#contenthead div.left span.cursos").removeClass("colorblue");
        $("div#contenthead div.left span.atendimento").removeClass("colorblue");
        $("div#contenthead div.left span.acaosocial").addClass("colorblue");
        $("div#contenthead div.left span.calendario").removeClass("colorblue");});

    $("div#contenthead div.left span.calendario").hover(function() {
        $("div#contenthead div.left span.cursos").removeClass("colorblue");
        $("div#contenthead div.left span.atendimento").removeClass("colorblue");
        $("div#contenthead div.left span.acaosocial").removeClass("colorblue");
        $("div#contenthead div.left span.calendario").addClass("colorblue");});

    $("div#contenthead div.right span.login").hover(function() {
        $("div#contenthead div.left span.cursos").removeClass("colorblue");
        $("div#contenthead div.left span.atendimento").removeClass("colorblue");
        $("div#contenthead div.left span.acaosocial").removeClass("colorblue");
        $("div#contenthead div.left span.calendario").removeClass("colorblue");});
</script>
```

### Ele serve para exibir elementos fora da div pai utilizando hovers em elementos distintos alterando cor e visibilidade.

Em relação a tamanho, a solução do @fernandomondo é a melhor, deixa o script muito pequeno e simples de editar, muito útil, mas o @tobymosque tocou em um assunto que sou muito valor, peso para o usuário final, mesmo que o dele seja maior, qual dos dois seria mais leve? tem alguma forma de calcular peso de script?

Comment: coloca um print do que acontece na tela quando hover... pode ser que apenas css resolva.

Comment: Minifica ele :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aparentemente você possui somente 4 `spans` dentro da `div.left`, e quando voçê coloca a class "colorBlue" em uma quer remover de todos as outras. 
Se este é o caso, e os span só possuem uma única classe, algo como:

```
<div id="contenthead">
   <div class="left">
    <span class="atendimento">Click</span>
```

Enão é só fazer assim:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("div#contenthead div.left span").hover(function() {
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu").addClass("displayblock");
        var topMenuClass = $(this).attr("class");
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul").removeClass("displayblock");
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul." + topMenuClass ).addClass("displayblock");
}, function(){
 $("div#contenthead div.topmenu").removeClass("displayblock");

});
    </script>
```

Caso os span tenham mais de uma classe, para não ter que fazer muita coisa, eu aconselho a usar um data attribute para facilitar:

```
<div id="contenthead">
   <div class="left">
    <span class="small atendimento" data-topmenu="atendimento">Click</span>
```

E o script ficaria assim:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("div#contenthead div.left span").hover(function() {
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu").addClass("displayblock");
        var topMenuClass = $(this).data("topmenu");
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul").removeClass("displayblock");
        $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul." + topMenuClass ).addClass("displayblock");
}, function(){
 $("div#contenthead div.topmenu").removeClass("displayblock");

});
    </script>
```

Edit: Sobre o seu comentário de não fechar o menu, isto ocorre porque você tem que remover a classe displayblock do topmenu quando o mouse sair de cima.
Neste caso, o evento hover, pode receber uma segunda function, para executar.

Comment: pow, em termos de tamanho, este é o menor de todos, funciona quase muito bem, mas, o mesmo dilema do @tobymosque, ele não fecha no login $("div#contenthead div.left span").hover(function() {
$("div#contenthead div.topmenu").addClass("displayblock");
var topMenuClass = $(this).data("topmenu");
$("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul").removeClass("displayblock");
$("div#contenthead div.left span").removeClass("colorblue");
$("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul." + topMenuClass ).addClass("displayblock");
$("div#contenthead div.left span." + topMenuClass ).addClass("colorblue");}) utilizei o segundo

Comment: editei a resposta, vê se ajuda.

Answer (score 7):

Solução simples apenas com CSS:

Implemente uma **classe CSS** que contenha as definições desejadas na pseudo-classe `hover`:

```
.hoverable:hover
{
    //conteúdo das classes displayblock e colorblue juntas.
}
```

**Adicione a classe** a todos os elementos, diretamente ou via o código *jQuery* abaixo:

```
$("div#contenthead div.left span.cursos").addClass("hoverable");
$("div#contenthead div.left span.atendimento").addClass("hoverable");
$("div#contenthead div.left span.acaosocial").addClass("hoverable");
$("div#contenthead div.left span.calendario").addClass("hoverable");
```

O resultado final será a aplicação das definições apenas quando o evento `:hover` acontecer no elemento sob o cursor.

Comment: +1 as vezes esquecemos das soluções mais simples. hehe

Answer (score 6):

você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
var topmenu = $("div#contenthead div.topmenu");
var leftSpan $("div#contenthead div.left span");
var listas = {};
var spams = {};

listas.cursos = $("ul.cursos", topmenu);
listas.atendimento = $("ul.atendimento", topmenu);
listas.acaosocial = $("ul.acaosocial", topmenu);
listas.calendario = $("ul.calendario", topmenu);    

spams.cursos = $("span.cursos", topmenu);
spams.atendimento = $("span.atendimento", topmenu);
spams.acaosocial = $("span.acaosocial", topmenu);
spams.calendario = $("span.calendario", topmenu);

var atualizarMenu = function (name) {
  for (var key in listas) {
    listas[key].removeClass("displayblock");
    spams[key].removeClass("colorblue");
  }
  if (name) {
    listas[name].addClass("displayblock");
    spams[name].addClass("colorblue");
  }
}

leftSpan.hover(function() { topmenu.addClass("displayblock"); });   
leftSpan.filter(".cursos").hover(function() { atualizarMenu("cursos"); });
leftSpan.filter(".atendimento").hover(function() { atualizarMenu("atendimento"); });
leftSpan.filter(".acaosocial").hover(function() { atualizarMenu("acaosocial"); });
leftSpan.filter(".calendario").hover(function() { atualizarMenu("calendario"); });
leftSpan.filter(".login").hover(function() { atualizarMenu(null); });
```

desta forma, você vai alem de diminuir código, vai diminuir o numero de consultas aos objetos DOM e diminuir a quantidade de memoria alocada pelo script.

Comment: Ficou bom e foi a primeira coisa que pensei

Comment: @flourigh, não edite a resposta para apontar um problema, apenas realize um comentário, mas já resolvi o mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Pra reduzir um pouco pode ser feito assim.

```
    $("div#contenthead div.left span.atendimento").hover(function() {
    $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.atendimento").addClass("displayblock");
    $("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.acaosocial,"+
    "div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.cursos,"+
    "div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.calendario").removeClass("displayblock");
```

Comment: valeu, ficou assim
mas o do @tobymosque seria muito bom, só não fecha

$("div#contenthead div.left span.cursos").hover(function() {
$("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.cursos").addClass("displayblock");
$("div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.atendimento,"+"div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.acaosocial,"+"div#contenthead div.topmenu ul.calendario").removeClass("displayblock");
$("div#contenthead div.left span.cursos").addClass("colorblue");
$("div#contenthead div.left span.atendimento,"+"div#contenthead div.left span.acaosocial,"+"div#contenthead div.left span.calendario").removeClass("colorblue");});